# ERROR: function dmetaphone(unknown) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want similar function like soundex('anne')

dmetaphone('anne')
when I am trying to execute above query . It will give following error.

> ERROR:  function dmetaphone(unknown) does not exist

Comment: Why do you think that the function `dmetaphone` should be exist?

Comment: i m trying another function like . soundex('anne') it will give same error

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to add the `fuzzystrmatch` extension. Make sure that the contrib modules are installed, then run the following as superuser

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

Then the function will be defined.